# How to find the possible key combinations after doing a partial combination?

Tags: key-bindings

I have set <kbd>,</kbd> as the leader in vim.
I have a plugin X to move to previous buffer set with key combination <kbd>,</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.
There is some plugin Y that has a combination <kbd>,</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>+<kbd>some_key</kbd>.
Now, to actually move to the previous buffer, I have to press <kbd>,</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>+<kbd>some_unrelated_key</kbd>. Basically vim is waiting for input after <kbd>,</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to decide if this completes the combination for plugin Y. So if I press <kbd>some_unrelated_key</kbd>, it sees there is no such combination and does <kbd>,</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> for plugin X, followed by whatever <kbd>some_unrelated_key</kbd> does.
**Question:** Is there a way to identify what the plugin Y is?

Comment: Try `:verbose map ,h` which will show you all normal-mode mappings starting with the `,h` prefix and the `:verbose` part should show you where it's defined. (I'd be happy to turn this into an answer if it does indeed help you fix your problem.) Feel free to [edit] your question and include relevant output of this command in your specific setup for more suggestions on how to work around or fix the conflict.

Comment: @filbranden That worked! Thank you. Please make this an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:verbose map ,h` command, which will show you all normal-mode mappings starting with the `,h` prefix.

The [`:verbose`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Averbose) modifier will have the `:map` command show you where the specific mappings were originally defined, which might be able to help you trace them back to a specific plug-in.